# Javascript if statement not working as intended

Tags: javascript, ajax, function

If you look [here](http://www.ewsprojects.com/~lyons) and try to click on the voting arrows, you'll see my problem. Now compare that to the homepage (click logo). Try voting there. The arrows change image based on vote. I also use a `in_array()` function to determine what the user has voted on and it produces the correct voting icon. This all works fine on the submission page I linked to. However, again, if you try clicking on the links, it always defaults to the else statement in this Javascript function:

I'll only show the function for liking, as I'm having the identical problem for the dislike.

```
function getVote(filename, num, idnum, user)
  {
    var like = document.getElementById('like_arrow' + num);
    var dislike = document.getElementById('dislike_arrow' + num);

  if (like.src.indexOf('../vote_triangle.png')!=-1 && dislike.src.indexOf('../vote_triangle_flip.png')!=-1) {
   like.src = '../vote_triangle_like.png';

         (AJAX to alter rating here)

  } else if (like.src.indexOf('../vote_triangle.png') != -1) {
   like.src = '../vote_triangle_like.png';
   dislike.src = '../vote_triangle_flip.png';

         (AJAX to alter rating here)

  } else {
   like.src = '../vote_triangle.png'; // Always defaults to this

         (AJAX to alter rating here)

  }

}
```

In case you're wondering, the `num` variable is what I use on the front page to differentiate between the submissions, they increment by one for each one. In this though, I just made that value blank in the function so it shouldn't affect anything. Might be my problem though, but I can't see how.

Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing what `like.src` and `dislike.src` are, we can't help.  Can you put in some logging and tell us what those values are when you don't think the `else` should be reached.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but try and `console.log(like.src)` and see what you get. *Then* try `console.log(like.src.indexOf('../vote_triangle.png')) and see what you get.

Comment: You need to practice your code formatting a bit.

Comment: @Mike, like is a variable that I get using `getElementById`, and the src is what I want to change, along with the rating, when people click on the voting icons. The problem is that it always seems to default to the `else` part. @David, I guess I'm not sure where you want me to put that. @lwburk It works for me! But I definitely do need to care more about that.

Comment: @MarkLyons, I understand what `like` is.  What I want to know is some sample values of `like.src` and `dislike.src` for which you are getting unexpected behavior.

Comment: @MikeSamuel if you look on the homepage. The src is, by default, the gray up arrow. It's `vote_triangle.png`, when you vote up something, the arrow changes to the green one: `vote_triangle_like.png`. It doesn't work this way on the submission page because it seems to always default to the else statement that is intended for reverting an upvote back to a regular, non vote.

Comment: @MarkLyons, None of that is telling me the particular string value that is `like.src`.  Your confusion is a result of a mismatch between expectations and reality.  The easiest way to clear that up is to find out what really is -- in this case that means finding out the exact value of `like.src`.

Comment: And BNL helped me understand why that was wrong with the src and why I couldn't use `../` for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`like.src` isn't going to contain `..\`. It may be as simple as removing that part.

Comment: The `../` is there because the submission files are in their own folder, and the images are in a folder lower.

Comment: But the DOM .src property isn't ever going to contain a relative path.

Comment: Should I try hosting the images in the submission folder as well and getting rid of the `../`s?

Comment: I would put all images in a /images folder and reference them from there.

Comment: But would it have to be within the folder where the submissions are contained?

Comment: No, it could be at the root level of your site. Then you would just always say `imageTag.src = "/~lyons/images/whatever.png"` regardless of what page you are referencing it from.

Comment: For whatever reason, it works now! I checked the first time and nothing was different and I just tried again now and it works great. Just did the same to the dislike function as well. Thanks for all the help!